# Change settings for file extensions in Expression Web 3

Tags: expression-web, microsoft-expression-web

I want to change how certain file extensions are treated within Microsoft Expression Web 3.  For example, *.inc should be treated like PHP includes, so they get PHP color coding and code hints.

Is this possible and how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's a pretty good rundown on how to do this at:

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=69

I'm not on my Windows machine right now, but I'm guessing if you configure the extension "inc" to open with "Expression Web (Open as HTML)", that should do the trick.

Comment: The problem isn't opening it, it's applying the color coding and code hints.